# Android TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY remove second window

Tags: android, manifest, layoutparams, android-windowmanager

I have an interesting problem.
When users get a call I show them a text and I am doing it with `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.
But in lock screen a second window shows up!
[Here's the image of the issue I'm having.](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ng6fqh&s=8#.VTEo8pPzNWo)

Thanks,

Here is my code:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
params.height = 150;
params.gravity = Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER;
nm.this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
TextView tv = new TextView (nm.this);
tv.setText ("Showing the error");
LinearLayout lo = new LinearLayout(nm.this);
lo.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
lo.addView(tv);
wm.addView (lo, params);
```

My Manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".nm"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nm" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: What's your goal exactly? I don't see what's the problem here..

Comment: If that window appears then it disables yes and no button and user has to push back button once then answer his/her phone. Therefore I need to remove that second small window. I don't even know how that one comes there. If the phone is not locked then it doesn't show up. Thanks,